# Mongodb check collection for same parameters

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, fetch, aggregation

I am trying to check does collection has other records with same params with mongodb aggregation. Example:

Car collection:

```
[
  {
    "year": "2020",
    "model": "Opel"
  }, {
    "year": "2020",
    "model": "Renault"
  }, {
    "year": "2019",
    "model": "Renault"
  },
]
```

Fetch: get records by year return:

```
[
   {
    "year": "2020",
    "model": "Opel"
  }, {
    "year": "2020",
    "model": "Renault"
  },
]
```

Add variable for each record - "Does current record with name {name} has another record in this table - true / false".
Expected result:

```
[ 
  {
    "year": "2020",
    "model": "Opel",
    "hasAnotherRecord": false
  }, {
    "year": "2020",
    "model": "Renault",
    "hasAnotherRecord": true
  }
]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: "get records by year " certainly does not return documents by `email`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit get documets by year = 2020

Comment: Your first result does not group by year. It groups by `model`. What is the condition to get `year: 2020` (and not 2019). Your requirements are not clear, please specify. Show the aggregation you did already.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I do not want to group by year. I just do $match { year: '2020' }

Comment: But why do you then expect `hasAnotherRecord: true` for Renault? There is no other Renault in 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure how efficient this pipeline would be but it returns your expected output:

```java
db.cars.aggregate(
    [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$model",
                "cars": { "$push": { "model": "$model", "year": "$year" }}}
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "cars": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$cars",
                        "as": "c",
                        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$c.year", "2020" ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "hasAnotherRecord": {
                    "$gt": [ { "$size": "$cars" }, 1 ]
                },
                "_id": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "$match": {
                "cars": {
                    "$ne": null,
                    "$not": { "$size": 0 }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "model": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [ "$cars.model", 0 ]
                },
                "year": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [ "$cars.year", 0 ]
                },
                "_id": 0
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

c# test program:

```js
using MongoDB.Entities;
using MongoDB.Entities.Core;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverFlow
{
    public class car : Entity
    {
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            new DB("test");

            new[] {
                new car { model= "opel", year= "2020"},
                new car { model= "renault", year= "2020"},
                new car { model= "renault", year= "2019"},
                new car { model= "nissan", year= "2021"}
            }.Save();

            var result = DB.Queryable<car>()
                           .GroupBy(c => c.model,
                                    (model, cars) => new
                                    {
                                        model,
                                        cars = cars.Select(c => new car
                                        {
                                            model = c.model,
                                            year = c.year
                                        })
                                    })
                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               cars = x.cars.Where(c => c.year == "2020"),
                               hasAnotherRecord = x.cars.Count() > 1
                           })
                           .Where(x => x.cars.Any())
                           .Select(x => new
                           {
                               x.cars.First().model,
                               x.cars.First().year
                           })
                           .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I do not want to use group, and I may want to check for multiple parameters, not only year how it is in example. Also I am working with big data, and yes, this solution has not optimal speed

Comment: I don't think **hard-coded** `year: "2020"` is desired.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit oops, ammended the answer.

Comment: @IntoTheDeep don't think it's possible to do this without a group stage. unless you take a totally different approach to your schema. you could store "model" in it's own collection and have a field for "numberOfCars" and keep track of how many cars are there for a model.